# Repeating some rows in some offsets in the PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, select, sql-order-by, pagination

Why sometimes Am I getting repeated row in different offsets when I'm using select, join, order by, offset & limit together?

```
select * from users u
left join posts p on p.user_id = u.id
order by u.id
offset 0, limit 20
```

Comment: Could you please provide the result that you received vs expected

Comment: Yes, Of Course. Please wait.

Comment: Is it possible that records have been inserted/deleted between the different calls to the database?

Comment: I'm not sure!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are sorting with a column (`amount`) that contains duplicate values. Your `order by` clause is not deterministic, hence the results are not stable.

A simple solution is to usea second sorting criteria in order to break the ties (it *looks* like `user(id)` can do this):

```
select *                                  -- better enumerate the columns here
from wallets w
inner join users u on u.id = w.user_id    -- your "left join" is actually "inner join"
where u.role = 'tester' and w.amount > 0
order by w.amount, u.id                   -- here is the second sorting criteria
offset 0, limit 20
```